# Call JQuery function on $event from ng-click

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a `div` with an `ng-click` where I call following function:

```
$scope.toggleLog = function($event){
     $event.currentTarget.slideToggle()
 }
```

When I look in the debugger the `$event.currentTarget` is pointing towards my div, so seems fine. However, the `slideToggle()` function is undefined. I have included JQuery. The `$event` is a jquery object and so is the `currentTarget`. So why am I not able to call any JQuery related functions on it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead of this line

```
$event.currentTarget.slideToggle()
```

Try using this way,

```
angular.element($event.currentTarget).slideToggle();
```

[angular.element](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) is an alias of jQuery in angularjs

> If jQuery is available, angular.element is an alias for the jQuery
>   function. If jQuery is not available, angular.element delegates to
>   Angular's built-in subset of jQuery, called "jQuery lite" or "jqLite."

Comment: Thanks, that works! Is there any advantage on using angular.element over wrapping the element between $() ?

Comment: I updated my answer, also please visit the link i included for better understanding. :D

Comment: When i read through the documentation there, i didn't see slideToggle() function available with jqLite, so in your case you must have jQuery available :-(

Answer (score 1):

`$event.currentTarget` is pointing to DOM element, not a jQuery object. Wrap it up in jQuery and then invoke `slideToggle`.

```
$($event.currentTarget).slideToggle();
```